# Обособление одиночного деепричастия несов.вида, стоящего в конце предложения

Tags: пунктуация, деепричастия

Моя больная тема с недавного времени - деепричастие и его необособление. И вот это предложение вызвало вопросы: "Спросил он () ухмыляясь". Нужна ли запятая перед "ухмыляясь" или нет? Мы можем сказать "спросил и ухмыльнулся", значит должны ставить запятую, но! "спросил с ухмылкой". Во втором случае уже не ставим. А дальше уже идут сомнения и попытки понять нюансы необособления деепричастий. Поэтому, пожалуйста, помогите мне разобраться в этом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Оба варианта возможны:** спросил он ухмылЯясь (с ухмылкой); спросИл он,  ухмылЯясь (и при этом ухмыльнулся). В первом варианте логическим ударением **подчеркнуто "ухмыляясь".**

Пояснение

1) Когда одиночное причастие стоит после глагола, то бывает трудно решить, что оно обозначает: второе действие или обстоятельство образа действия, как наречие. Решение этой задачи может быть факультативным, но при этом надо ориентироваться на структуру и интонацию предложения.

2) Рассмотрим примеры:

― Какая неожиданность, Олексин, ― **сказал он, ухмыляясь**. ― Удивлены? [Борис Васильев. Картежник и бретер, игрок и дуэлянт (1998)]

Сколько лет сколько зим, ― **сказал он, ухмыляясь.** [Аркадий Вайнер, Георгий Вайнер. Лекарство против страха (1987)]

Но расплачиваться, конечно, придется, а как же ― товар ― деньги ― товар, ― **продолжал он ухмыляясь,** ― у меня есть хобби, я, знаете ли, коллекционер. [Нина Катерли. Коллекция доктора Эмиля (1981)]

«Ведь что он придумал, ― **говорил он ухмыляясь**. [Б. Н. Чичерин. Воспоминания (1894)]

3) Вот пример без обособления: **Продолжал он ухмылЯясь (с ухмылкой)**.

Здесь на деепричастие падает логическое ударение, а на глагол ударение не падает, пауза при этом отсутствует. Тем не менее  выбор варианта  факультативный, расстановку ударений можно изменить и обособить деепричастие: **ПродолжАл он, ухмылЯясь .**

4) Обязательное обособление при  положении деепричастия между подлежащим и сказуемым: Он, **ухмыляясь,** покачал головой.